# How to debug a program that is counting items incorrectly?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I am creating an Online Examination System. I managed to show the questions and take the answer and post the answers for checking. My problem is that, after checking the result is true, it's give me wrong answer.

I have 4 question and after select all the correct answer it return 3 marks. What can I do to debug the problem?

**Resultprocess.java**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

          int count=0;
          for(int i=1;i<=4;i++) {
        String ans =request.getParameter("option"+i);
         System.out.println(ans);
            Answer Answer= new Answer();
            Answer.setAnswer(ans);
            CTest cans =new CTest();
            boolean ansercheck = cans.getans(Answer);
            if(ansercheck==true) {

                count++;    
            }
        }
          HttpSession session = request.getSession();
          String answer=Integer.toString(count);
          session.setAttribute("answer", answer); 

          response.sendRedirect("result.jsp");
        }
}
```

**CTest.java**

```
public class CTest {
    Connection cn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ConnectionFac con = new ConnectionFac();
    String selectans = "select Answer from ctest  ";
    public boolean getans( Answer answer) {

            try {
                rs = con.getResultSet(selectans);
                while(rs.next()) {

                    String answerDB = rs.getString(1);

                    Answer ansdb= new Answer();
                    ansdb.setAnswer(answerDB);

                    if(answer.equals(ansdb)) {
                        return true;    
                    }
                }

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        return false;
    }
}
```

**result.jsp**

```
<div  class="col-sm-8" >
<form action="#">
<%
  String marks= (String)session.getAttribute("answer");
  out.print("<font size='5' color='White' >");
   out.print(" you got " +marks + " marks");
   out.print("</font>");
%>
</form>
  </div>
```

**Answer.java**`getter,setter and equals`

```
package exam.DTO;

public class Answer {
    String answer;

    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof Answer))
            return false;
        Answer other = (Answer) obj;
        if (answer == null) {
            if (other.answer != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!answer.equals(other.answer))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You are posting a lot of code, with a very vague and unspecific question. Please take some effort to describe your problem and reduce your code to a [mcve].

Comment: This is a classic debugging problem. Normally I would recommend printing intermediate values to the console, but `Resultprocess.java` looks like it is part of a web process. In that case, I suggest you send your intermediate values to a file (in append mode) so you can see a "log" of what is happening. That said, I can see you have a `System.out.println(ans)` in there already - can you see that on a console? If so, which of the loop iterations (1-4) is behaving wrongly?

Comment: Yes `System.out.println(ans)` print all answer on the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I have spotted the problem. It's basically a logic problem.

You are wanting `CTest` to give you a true/false as to whether an Answer is correct or not. To do that, you would need to supply to it some sort of question reference, so it can look up the correct answer.

However, what you are doing in this class is looping through the answers until *any* matching one is found.

For example, let's say the correct answers are:

1. A
2. B
3. C
4. D

and the answers given in the test are all wrong:

1. D
2. C
3. B
4. A

The system would be able to find each of these answers, and so would return true (correct) for each one. I assume that is not the behaviour you are seeking.

I think your bug is firstly here:

```
public boolean getans( Answer answer) {
```

This needs some sort of question reference - either a Question instance, if you have any such thing, or perhaps just an integer ID.

Then you would need to change this so that a parameter is sent into it (adjust based on your column name and how to parameterise in Java):

```
String selectans = "select Answer from ctest WHERE qid = ?";
```

Finally, you would need to inject the appropriate question ID here:

```
rs = con.getResultSet(selectans);
```

Comment: how can i pass the qid?

Comment: Well, the simplest approach would be `boolean ansercheck = cans.getans(Answer, i)`, but it depends on how you have stored question IDs in your database. Are they integers from 1-4, as per your loop? If they can be other numbers (e.g. you pick 4 questions at random from a larger number) then you will need to store the question ID in the form too. You could then return it using `qid = request.getParameter("qid"+i)`.